# Error During up the first Network using CouchDB

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

while join the peer to the channel got the following error:-

> Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Note that:-

**I have used CouchDb. write the following command:-**

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do some validation against the **docker-compose-couch.yaml** and your old file, I asume that you replace it but the file is still there.

Validate that all the services are pointing to use CouchDB now, maybe the **docker-compose-cli.yaml** is pointing to the other DB type.

```
  peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # # bridge network as the peers
  # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
  # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
  # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
# command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 7053:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
extra_hosts:
- "peer1.org1.example.com:209.97.128.176"
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - couchdb
networks:
  - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic
```

In the example you have one peer service and the couchDB service, you can take it as example.

Also, I have a tutorial of how to setup a Hyperledger Fabric in mutiple hosts based in the Basic Network example of the Fabric Samples. Maybe you can take it as reference.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4

Regards!